# Audio repair service

Tags: audio

I have some damaged audio from a video I recently took. Is there anyone interested in attempting to repair for me< happy to pay if need be.

Comment: That's not really what this site is for, but I guess if you posted a clip somewhere we could at least perhaps tell you if it was fixable.

Comment: were you recording seperate sound or is the audio corrupt on the camera?

Comment: The other issue is a commercial one. If it can be fixed in a single pass after some parameter tweaks, that would cost you about £100. If it needed faffing with all day, that would be 5 to 800 - I tend to price in an "annoyance factor" for faffy jobs ;-)).

Comment: Ok, I’m pretty sure it’s because my Rode external mic wasn’t plugged in right to my iphone. It’s severely distorted. I was going to have a look at some of the distortion/audio tools online but thought I’d ask for help first.

Comment: I was hoping maybe there was a one pass quick fix low cost option but I’m thinking that’s a no.